# (Super basic) Batch file that duplicates, renames and deletes itself

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm looking to create a simple batch file in .bat that (in order):
duplicates in the same folder
renames itself 
renames the duplicate
and in the end deletes itself

It's more an experimentation in useless action more than a useful batch.
I'm not good with coding, I understand it's not to complicated but I can't get the copy/paste part.

For what I was able to do was only the renaming part (as for the first bat itself, I can't get to the duplicate and I wouldn't even know how to do it.)

```
@ECHO OFF
RENAME %0 name.bat
DEL %0
```

I obviously need the copy/paste part and, if the batch duplicates what will be the name of the new file? name(1).bat? I need to work on the new file too, as much as I work with the file itself %0 does the trick but I don't know how to call specifics files.

Sorry for the naivness and thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I follow you correctly, although I don't fully understand the purpose of the intended action, you could try something like this:

**sdel.cmd**

```
@copy "%~f0" "%~f0.tmp"
@del "%~f0" & @rename "%~f0.tmp" "%~nx0"
```

This batch-file script will copy itself (`sdel.cmd`) to a file called `sdel.cmd.tmp`. Then it deletes itself and renames the duplicate file `sdel.cmd.tmp` to `sdel.cmd`.

---

> Very good, this was sure what I was looking for, but what if I wanted
>   to make that these names contained progressive numbers?

This will somewhat complicate things. Unless I'm completely overlooking something right now, using part of the file name as the sequence number for the duplicated file introduces a limitation as to what the original file can be called like in the first place.

The following example uses a hyphen (`-`) to separate the file name from the sequence number. In order for the batch-file script to work correctly, the original file name shouldn't contain any hyphens. The sequence number is limited to 32-bits of precision (signed).

String substitution operations are used to separate the file name from the sequence number. The first operation removes any text up to and including the first occurrence of a hypen, only the sequence number remains. The second operation discards any occurrence of the sequence number prefixed with a hyphen, only the file name remains.

With the use of the sequence number, the rename operation is no longer necessary because the final file name of the duplicate file will always differ from the original file name.

**sdel.cmd**

```
@echo off

setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
set "qpath=%~f0"
set "name=%~n0"

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "delim=-"
set "count=!name:*%delim%=!"
set "name=!name:%delim%%count%=!"
set /a "count+=1"

copy "!qpath!" "!name!%delim%%count%%~x0"
del "!qpath!"
```

**Result**

```
sdel.cmd   ---> sdel-1.cmd
sdel-1.cmd ---> sdel-2.cmd
...
sdel-2147483647.cmd  ---> sdel--2147483648.cmd
sdel--2147483648.cmd ---> sdel--2147483647.cmd
```

Comment: Very good, this was sure what I was looking for, but what if I wanted to make that these names contained progressive numbers? Ex. original name is n1. I run the exe once and the new one is n2. Twice and is n3. An so on?

Super thanks for your previous help though

Comment: Or what if I need to add a word to the previous name? Could something like that be done? Ex.: name > new name > new new name > new new new name

Comment: @XXX I've added another version of the script to my answer which should meet the requirements of your first comment.